# Implicit function theorem for higher derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem, submanifold

We can find the statement of the theorem for continuously differentiable $f$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem.

Its also interestingly remarked that if $f$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable than we can choose $U$ so that $g$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable. How can we prove this using the theorem? I need this statement to prove some equivalent characterizations for sub-manifolds. Thank you!

Comment: You may choose $U$ so that $g$ is also $k-$ times differentiable. The statement that $U$ is $k-$ times differentiable does not make sense. The theorem includes a representtion for the the derivative (resp the partial derivativies) of $g$ in terms of $g$ (not differentiated) and the derivatives of $f$. From this representation higher continuous differentiabiliy of $g$ follows immediately by induction if you know that $f$ is sufficiently often (continuously). differentiable.

Comment: @Thomas Fixed the typo. And yeah that makes sense, thanks!